# Pasting array values and pasting normally

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, paste

I've been having issues with this VBA program today, it has been working great for a couple of days and now its kicking up a stink. I hav.nt changed anything that I am aware of to cause this problem since its a simple copy and paste and just setting a cell value to that of the array. I've played around with it and looked for answers but can't seem to get anything to fix it.

```
Worksheets(1).Select
For i = 1 To N
    Worksheets(1).Cells(3 + i, 1).Value = Current(i)
Next i

For h = 1 To holidays
    Worksheets(h).Select
    Range(Worksheets(h).Cells(4, 6), Worksheets(h).Cells(4 + N, 100)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial
    For f = 1 To N
        For i = 1 To N
        If Position(i) = f Then

            Range(Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(f, 1), Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(f, 100)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Worksheets(h).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, 6).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
        Next i
    Next f
Next h
End Sub
```

The first line where there are bugs is ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial, I've tried normal paste and pastespecial, pasting an entire row and a defined range. But nothing seems to get it to work.

The second line where there are bugs is Worksheets(1).Cells(3 + i, 1).Value = Current(i),
this worked up until today, so I don't understand why it has stopped, current(i) is a 1D array value which is a name such as "TONY BUGGENS".

The whole program is a sorting program, so it sorts the names in the array then pastes them over the original names in the spreadsheet.

Thanks for your help guys, I'm sure theres probably something simple I have overlooked. It's been an early morning.

Cheers,
Amy

Comment: Okay, I found the solution for the second line, the worksheet auto-protects itself on opening, I did not realise since it isn't my worksheet. But the first one still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Activesheet, rather name your sheet in the following style:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheetname")
```

Activesheet may lead to bugs eventually.
Also, instead of copy-pasting, assign values in this style:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheet("Destination").range("A1:B2").Value = Thisworkbook.Sheet("Source").range("A1:B2").Value
```

Make sure that source and destination range always have the same size.
Of course, it is ok to use cells, the way you do it.

As for the second bug, the best you can do is make use of the VBA "Locals window", which shows you your local variables. Your code doesn't show what is being filled in the array, but you can verify it in the Locals window. You can also use:

```
debug.print current(i)
```

to verify what the array contains. If the array contains values or objects that it can't assign, then you need to verify what is assigned to the array

```
current(i) = <???>
```

Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for the reply. I fixed the second one, the sheet isn't mine you see so I'm fixing other people's problems, the worksheet reprotects itself after it is opened, which I did not realise. As for the first one, I did originally have Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheetname") and changed it to activesheet when searching for a solution, so this will not work, but I will change it back as you have said it can cause problems. I believe I need to copy and paste because it is not just values that need to be translated but the interior colour of the cells as well. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Using RGB, the syntax is: Thisworkbook.Sheet(1).Range("A1:A5").Interior.Color = RGB(0,0,0) (to be filled in)

Comment: The spreadsheet is a holiday sheet, so there are several colours in use over each line and many gaps, using that method, i would have to set the value and colour of each cell seperately and scroll along the lines. Surely there must be a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: If you can use conditional format for your appliation, this would be the most efficient.

Comment: Okay I found the problem, the original guy who made the sheet made a macro for each sheet so that if any changes were made another macro ran, so I think this cleared the clipboard so there was nothing to paste. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problems were that the sheets had inbuilt macros that ran whever anything was changed in the sheet. This happened during my program which I believe was clearing my clipboard and making it try to paste nothing.

The second problem was due to the program autoprotecting itself.

The whole spreadsheet is a mess due to the programmer who made it clearly not doing a good job, I've drawn the short straw sorting it out.

Thanks for all your help guys, I might need it again soon.